# Importing/Exporting color themes for the MATLAB editor

Tags: matlab, color-scheme

Is there a way (maybe undocumented?) of importing/exporting color themes for the MATLAB editor?

As an example, I would like to import the [Zenburn](http://slinky.imukuppi.org/zenburnpage/) color scheme in MATLAB.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The color settings are saved in the *matlab.prf* file. You can find its location by running the command:

```
prefdir
```

There are a number of lines that start with the word *Colors*, for example:

```
ColorsBackground=C-16506839
ColorsMLintAutoFixBackground=C-3454186
ColorsText=C-8153962
ColorsUseMLintAutoFixBackground=Btrue
ColorsUseSystem=Bfalse
Colors_HTML_HTMLLinks=C-7102047
Colors_M_Comments=C-10981771
Colors_M_Errors=C-2346449
Colors_M_Keywords=C-8021760
Colors_M_Strings=C-13983336
Colors_M_SystemCommands=C-7613747
Colors_M_UnterminatedStrings=C-2935166
Colors_M_Warnings=C-27648
```

You can save those lines as your "theme" and then share them with others. They just have to replace the *Colors** lines with yours.

I would recommend opening the *matlab.prf* file in some text editor and then sorting the lines to make it easier to select only the lines of interest.

Comment: [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) can sort the lines of a text file as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3958364/1797098)

Answer (score 14):

I got so annoyed by the lack of a colour scheme/theme import and export facility in MATLAB when trying to move my own custom made theme between my MATLAB installations, I went and made a package which does just this.

The end result, called [MATLAB Schemer](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/53862-matlab-schemer), is rather comprehensive. In addition to the main colours described in Alexandre Chabot's post, it will also import and export editor colours, the status of toggleable settings such as right-hand line limit and cell mode, and the colours for syntax highlighting in other languages supported by MATLAB (C, C++, Java, XML, HTML, some Simulink things). Additionally, if a MATLAB-only theme is imported, it will be generalised to apply the theme in the other languages too.

It is available on the [MATLAB FileExchange](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/53862-matlab-schemer) and on [GitHub](https://github.com/scottclowe/matlab-schemer).

I implemented a few color schemes myself, but did not implement the Zenburn scheme. Since this post is from a few years ago now, I assume you have long ago resolved your problem of setting MATLAB to use colours from the Zenburn theme. If so, you could create a Zenburn theme by exporting the colour preferences you currently have simply by running `schemer_export()` in the MATLAB terminal. You could also share it by adding it to the [repository of colour schemes](https://github.com/scottclowe/matlab-schemes).

I hope this is helpful (if not to you than to somebody else at least).