# Setup Sublime Text or alternative editor for Matlab?

Tags: matlab, editor, syntax-highlighting

I did not find any suitable answer or hint, so I am asking this here now: Is there any alternative editor for Matlab with a dark theme (easier to the eyes), that supports integration in Matlab for proper debugging, autocompletition etc.? And if so, how do I setup those editors on windows?

I am really annoyied of the default matlab text editor. The color theme can not be applied to the whole IDE and the syntax highlightning is really bad, because it can not distinguish between numbers, brackets, operation-symbols (=,+,- etc.) and more like that. It is sometimes really hard to read a matlab file in the default editor, because the lack of these basic features.

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you submit this as a feature request to the MathWorks. I'm fairly sure that there is no way to use a different editor for debugging, but you can configure MATLAB to launch a different editor when you type `edit` in the command window.

Comment: Also, if you think a dark theme is easier on the eyes, you need to turn down the brightness of your monitor. :)

Comment: I think turn down brightness does not work. There is a reason for dark themes in Visual Studio and other IDE. It is not just cool, but better for working.

Comment: I think there's a historical reason for dark backgrounds, and people still use them because that's what they're used to, but I don't see the purpose with modern monitors. I personally find it harder to read white text on a black background, because I'm used to reading black text on a white background (like in books and stuff).

Comment: Hm, this might actually be a subjective thing, depending on the user. What I did notice is, that more often dark themes are implemented in different software. And if a dark themen is available, I tend to use it over the bright default theme. This way I can better focus on the code.

Comment: You can customize the colors of MATLAB, Preferences -> Colors. Its is pretty flexible.

Comment: Customizing colors in Matlab is very basic, as I mentioned. The syntax highligthning is very important and matlab itself provides a very bad color syntax. If you are used to VS or other IDEs, you will notice how much readability is lost in these matlab files.

Comment: You can literally set custom colours for every word type (and the background) individually in the preferences. If this is the only motivation to use another editor then it's a pointless endeavour...

Comment: Matlab color syntax does not allow to distinguish between operators (+/- /= etc.), variables, function names, function arguments, brackets ("{[["), points in nested structs (".") and so on. These elements are all displayed in the same color, and this leads to bad readability.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33676920/2605073).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking back at my own question, I will try to give an answer. There is no way to define individual colors for matlab-code in matlab itself. Therefore I stick with Notepad or Atom, which have far superior color syntax even for matlab code. For running the code, you have to switch to matlab of course. This for sure no optimal solution, but the best to get better readability for matlab code.