# Notepad++ how to delete duplicate

Tags: regex, notepad++, duplicates

I need do delete duplicate rows with case sensitive.

```
Hello
hello
Hello
```

Need to:

```
Hello
hello
```

How can i do this?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3958350/1870232) may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](http://madhutomy.blogspot.in/2013/06/removing-duplicate-rows-from-notepad.html):

> First download and install the TextFX plugin, instructions given
>   below.
>
> 1. Download the plugin from SourceForge: http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/npp-plugins/TextFX/TextFX%20v0.26/TextFX.v0.26.unicode.bin.zip
> 2. Open the zip file and extract NppTextFX.dll
> 3. Place NppTextFX.dll in the Notepad++ plugins directory, such as: C:\Program Files\Notepad++\plugins
> 4. Start Notepad++, and TextFX will be one of the file menu items
> 5. Check the following options
>
> a) +Sort ascending
>
> b) +Sort outputs only UNIQUE (at column) lines

[image]

> 6. Then select a block of text (ctrl+A to select the entire document). Then click "Sort lines case sensitive" or "Sort lines case
>      insensitive"