# How to remove all lines that occur more than once

Tags: notepad++

Im using notepad++ and i have a have large text file with lots of lines that all contain a string with no spaces, I need a way to remove all lines that occur more than once.

For example:

```
    name1
    name1
    name2
    name3
    name4
    name4
    name5
```

Would be changed to

```
    name2
    name3
    name5
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958350/removing-duplicate-rows-in-notepad

Comment: nope that leaves a single occurrence of the line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for `^(.*?\R)\1+` and replace with nothing.

From start of line `^`, find all characters `.*?` until the linebreak `\R`. Then repeat `\1` the search from `()` one or more times `+`.

Use regular expression search mode.

Lines must be sorted before doing this.

Last line must end with linebreak, or it will not be matched.