# How to remove both matching lines while removing duplicates

Tags: regex, csv, text, editor, notepad++

I have a large text file containing a list of emails called "main", and I have sent mails to some of them. I have a list of 'sent' emails. Now, I want to remove the 'sent' emails from the list "main".

In other words, I want to remove both the matching raw from the text file while removing duplicates. Example:

I have:

```
email@email.com
test@test.com
email@email.com
```

I want:

```
test@test.com
```

Is there any easier way to achieve this? Please suggest a tool or method to do this, but please consider the text file is larger than 10MB.

Comment: Does Notepadd++ support regex/scripting?

Comment: You can probably use power shells compare-object cmdlet http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156812.aspx

Comment: I am not completely sure about your requirements. But if your main and the send list are in the same file, maybe [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16293580/626273) can help you.

Comment: @leopard121 What do you mean by `remove both the matching raw from the text file`?

Comment: @stema thanks for the link. The code works, but does not remove all the matching rows. I mean, if there're 10 duplicate rows, it remove the nine, but I need to remove all.

Comment: @cullub I want to remove all matching rows. Please see the example.

Answer (score 0):

In terminal:

```
cat test| sort | uniq -c | awk -F" " '{if($1==1) print $2}'
```

Comment: can you please elaborate your answer a little bit?

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

I use [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) a lot for such tasks, as the unix command line is incredibly powerful.

Here's how to achieve what you want:

```
cat main.txt | sort -u | grep -Fvxf sent.txt
```

`sort -u` will remove duplicates (by sorting the `main.txt` file first), and `grep` will take care of removing the unwanted addresses.

Here's what the `grep` options mean:

- `-F` plain text search
- `-v` invert results
- `-x` will force the whole line to match the pattern
- `-f` read patterns from the specified file

Oh, and if your files are in the Windows format (`CR LF` newlines) you'll rather have to do this:

```
cat main.txt | dos2unix | sort -u | grep -Fvxf <(cat sent.txt | dos2unix)
```

Just like with the Windows command line, you can simply add:

```
> output.txt
```

at the end of the command line to redirect the output to a text file.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But is there any way to do this in Notepad++ or any other similar windows based software.

Comment: That's too much to ask for a text editor to handle, but cygwin is for windows.