# Remove duplicates from text file based on second text file

Tags: regex, bash, unix, text, editor

How can I remove all lines from a text file (`main.txt`) by checking a second textfile (`removethese.txt`). What is an **efficient approach** if files are greater than 10-100mb. [Using mac]

#### Example:

```
main.txt
3
1
2
5
```

Remove these lines

```
removethese.txt
3
2
9
```

Output:

```
output.txt
1
5
```

Example Lines (these are the actual lines I'm working with - order does not matter):

```
ChIJW3p7Xz8YyIkRBD_TjKGJRS0
ChIJ08x-0kMayIkR5CcrF-xT6ZA
ChIJIxbjOykFyIkRzugZZ6tio1U
ChIJiaF4aOoEyIkR2c9WYapWDxM
ChIJ39HoPKDix4kRcfdIrxIVrqs
ChIJk5nEV8cHyIkRIhmxieR5ak8
ChIJs9INbrcfyIkRf0zLkA1NJEg
ChIJRycysg0cyIkRArqaCTwZ-E8
ChIJC8haxlUDyIkRfSfJOqwe698
ChIJxRVp80zpcEARAVmzvlCwA24
ChIJw8_LAaEEyIkR68nb8cpalSU
ChIJs35yqObit4kR05F4CXSHd_8
ChIJoRmgSdwGyIkRvLbhOE7xAHQ
ChIJaTtWBAWyVogRcpPDYK42-Nc
ChIJTUjGAqunVogR90Kc8hriW8c
ChIJN7P2NF8eVIgRwXdZeCjL5EQ
ChIJizGc0lsbVIgRDlIs85M5dBs
ChIJc8h6ZqccVIgR7u5aefJxjjc
ChIJ6YMOvOeYVogRjjCMCL6oQco
ChIJ54HcCsaeVogRIy9___RGZ6o
ChIJif92qn2YVogR87n0-9R5tLA
ChIJ0T5e1YaYVogRifrl7S_oeM8
ChIJwWGce4eYVogRcrfC5pvzNd4
```

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Take a look at `grep`'s man page.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen I tried several solutions including this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25954013/how-to-remove-both-matching-lines-while-removing-duplicates, but my lists are large and unsorted. But the solution doesn't filter lists.

Comment: With text editor UltraEdit available for Windows, Linux and Mac it can be done using an UE script, see [Delete lines in the active document containing strings listed in another file](https://www.ultraedit.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=52&t=7549).

Comment: @mofi does the UltraEdit handle large files (10-100mb files)?

Comment: @Emma UltraEdit can edit files of any size, even files with more than 4 GB on an x86 machine having just 2 GB RAM. But UltraEdit is by default configured for small file editing. For editing large and huge files some features should be disabled, see IDM power tip [Large file text editor](http://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials_power_tips/ultraedit/large_file_handling.html).

Comment: Fast version with `grep`: `LC_ALL=C fgrep -vxf removethese.txt main.txt >output.txt`.  The main points being: (1) use `fgrep` instead of plain `grep`; (2) use `-x` to match entire lines; (3) disable locales.

Comment: @icd047 ill give this a try. Will using `fgrep` make this significantly faster?

Comment: `fgrep` is the same as `grep -F`

Comment: @mofi I have a list of solutions to try (UltraEdit included). I added sample lines to the question. To answer your question the lines removed should 100% identical in case and length. Would you mind adding an answer with your UltraEdit solution?

Comment: You say order does not matter.  You could start with eliminating duplicates in both removethese.txt as well as main.txt by using `sort -u`

Comment: If 'removethese.txt' is fixed, or its a 1 off thing, I would break apart the find file into 2 MB chunks, create a multi-level trie regex for each chunk using this tool http://www.regexformat.com and run each one against 'main.txt'. I would bet its the fastest way to do it.

Comment: Ex: `ChIJ(?:0(?:8x-0kMayIkR5CcrF-xT6ZA|T5e1YaYVogRifrl7S_oeM8)|39HoPKDix4kRcfdIrxIVrqs|54HcCsaeVogRIy9___RGZ6o|6YMOvOeYVogRjjCMCL6oQco|C8haxlUDyIkRfSfJOqwe698|IxbjOykFyIkRzugZZ6tio1U|N7P2NF8eVIgRwXdZeCjL5EQ|Rycysg0cyIkRArqaCTwZ-E8|TUjGAqunVogR90Kc8hriW8c|W3p7Xz8YyIkRBD_TjKGJRS0|aTtWBAWyVogRcpPDYK42-Nc|c8h6ZqccVIgR7u5aefJxjjc|i(?:aF4aOoEyIkR2c9WYapWDxM|f92qn2YVogR87n0-9R5tLA|zGc0lsbVIgRDlIs85M5dBs)|k5nEV8cHyIkRIhmxieR5ak8|oRmgSdwGyIkRvLbhOE7xAHQ|s(?:35yqObit4kR05F4CXSHd_8|9INbrcfyIkRf0zLkA1NJEg)|w(?:8_LAaEEyIkR68nb8cpalSU|WGce4eYVogRcrfC5pvzNd4)|xRVp80zpcEARAVmzvlCwA24)`

Comment: The other option is code. And probably the better option if this is something you will do a lot. For that you'd probably need C++. Generally, dynamically create a ternary tree from the removethese file. Read in the main.txt file line by line, search tree. Simple, you're done !!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two standard ways to do this:

With `grep`:

```
grep -vxFf removethese main
```

This uses:

- `-v` to invert the match.
- `-x` match whole line, to prevent, for example, `he` to match lines like `hello` or `highway to hell`.
- `-F`  to use fixed strings, so that the parameter is taken as it is, not interpreted as a regular expression.
- `-f` to get the patterns from another file. In this case, from `removethese`.

With `awk`:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {a[$0];next} !($0 in a)' removethese main
1
5
```

Like this we store every line in `removethese` in an array `a[]`. Then, we read the `main` file and just print those lines that are not present in the array.

Comment: I previously tried `grep -vFf removethese.txt main.txt >output.txt` from the other answer and it took 4-6 hours to process a 7mb file. Do you think `awk` would yield a significantly faster result?

Comment: @Emma it is difficult to say because I don't have any sample of data, neither a vision on what file is bigger. You can give a try with a small sample and compare the two approaches. Note I am also using `-x` in the `grep` approach.

Comment: I added some sample lines to the question. I will give this method a try once my process completes for one of the other answers. Would it help for me to add a sample text file?

Comment: @Emma What is the proportion of size between the two files? `awk` can be extremely fast if the `removethese` file is not very big, meaning you don't have to keep in memory a lot of stuff.

Comment: the `removethese` file is fairly large. often half the size of the `main` file. It can range from 5mb to 50mb.

Comment: @Emma If you have RAM enough to store all this info in memory (which should be the case, according to what you comment in the other answer), this `awk` would be the best. I was recently astonished on how fast it processes data in [How to get the biggest number in a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30592249/1983854)

Comment: awk is quiquer  than grep !

Answer (score 5):

**With `grep`:**

```
grep -vxFf removethese.txt main.txt >output.txt
```

**With `fgrep`:**

```
fgrep -vxf removethese.txt main.txt >output.txt
```

`fgrep` is deprecated. `fgrep --help` says:

> Invocation as 'fgrep' is deprecated; use 'grep -F' instead.

**With `awk` (from @fedorqui):**

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$0];next} !($0 in a)' removethese.txt main.txt >output.txt
```

**With `sed`:**

```
sed "s=^=/^=;s=$=$/d=" removethese.txt | sed -f- main.txt >output.txt
```

This will fail if *removethese.txt* contains special chars. For that you can do:

```
sed 's/[^^]/[&]/g; s/\^/\\^/g' removethese.txt >newremovethese.txt
```

and use this *newremovethese.txt* in the `sed` command. But this is not worth the effort, it's too slow compared to the other methods.

---

**Test performed on the above methods:**

The `sed` method takes too much time and not worth testing.

Files Used:

```
removethese.txt : Size: 15191908 (15MB)     Blocks: 29672   Lines: 100233
main.txt : Size: 27640864 (27.6MB)      Blocks: 53992   Lines: 180034
```

Commands:
`grep -vxFf` | `fgrep -vxf` | `awk`

Taken Time:
`0m7.966s` | `0m7.823s` | `0m0.237s`
`0m7.877s` | `0m7.889s` | `0m0.241s`
`0m7.971s` | `0m7.844s` | `0m0.234s`
`0m7.864s` | `0m7.840s` | `0m0.251s`
`0m7.798s` | `0m7.672s` | `0m0.238s`
`0m7.793s` | `0m8.013s` | `0m0.241s`

AVG
`0m7.8782s` | `0m7.8468s` | `0m0.2403s`

This test result implies that `fgrep` is a little bit faster than `grep`.

**The `awk` method (from @fedorqui) passes the test with flying colors (`0.2403 seconds` only !!!).**

Test Environment:

```
HP ProBook 440 G1 Laptop
8GB RAM
2.5GHz processor with turbo boost upto 3.1GHz
RAM being used: 2.1GB
Swap being used: 588MB
RAM being used when the grep/fgrep command is run: 3.5GB
RAM being used when the awk command is run: 2.2GB or less
Swap being used when the commands are run: 588MB (No change)
```

**Test Result:**

Use the `awk` method.

Comment: @shellter would you mind suggesting a simpler way to do this?

Comment: @shellter yap I tested it (and it works)... But your suggestion works great, it can be done with a single line command..awesome.. thanks...

Comment: If your original solution worked, you should leave it in your answer. I'm skeptical that `echo $(grep something output.txt) > output.txt` won't overwrite the existing content of output.txt, but it was late, maybe it would work. In any case, I would recommend the `grep -vFf ...` solution. Good luck to all!

Comment: @shellter even if it worked the later is better. And for clarification, the previous grep was overwriting the contents and that was intentional...

Comment: @shellter No, the output.txt is modified (`sed -i`). It won't print any output to screen, it will delete those lines inplace in `output.txt`.

Comment: @shelter I've tried the `grep` method on a 8mb file and it took over 5 hours. Is there a chance that this is inefficient for large files?

Comment: @Emma what about the sed solution with while loop ?

Comment: @jahid I was about to give that a try. But each trial takes up several hours. Do you think it will be drastically more efficient?

Comment: @Emma I can't say without testing.. unfortunately I don't have a text file that large at hand...:D

Comment: @Emma I created a removethese.txt (15MB) and main.txt (27MB). The grep method took 7.525s. Don't use the sed method, it takes way more time.

Comment: @jahid interesting how quickly yours finished. I'm using 10mb ram macbook pro (mid 2012) and process took over 5 hours. Any idea why there's such a big difference? I updated the question with the typical line.

Comment: @Emma added test results for various methods and found the `awk` method to be the fastest...

Answer (score 3):

Here are a lot of the simple and effective solutions I've found: http://www.catonmat.net/blog/set-operations-in-unix-shell-simplified/

You need to use one of `Set Complement` bash commands. 100MB files can be solved within seconds or minutes.

**Set Membership**

```
$ grep -xc 'element' set    # outputs 1 if element is in set
                            # outputs >1 if set is a multi-set
                            # outputs 0 if element is not in set

$ grep -xq 'element' set    # returns 0 (true)  if element is in set
                            # returns 1 (false) if element is not in set

$ awk '$0 == "element" { s=1; exit } END { exit !s }' set
# returns 0 if element is in set, 1 otherwise.

$ awk -v e='element' '$0 == e { s=1; exit } END { exit !s }'
```

**Set Equality**

```
$ diff -q <(sort set1) <(sort set2) # returns 0 if set1 is equal to set2
                                    # returns 1 if set1 != set2

$ diff -q <(sort set1 | uniq) <(sort set2 | uniq)
# collapses multi-sets into sets and does the same as previous

$ awk '{ if (!($0 in a)) c++; a[$0] } END{ exit !(c==NR/2) }' set1 set2
# returns 0 if set1 == set2
# returns 1 if set1 != set2

$ awk '{ a[$0] } END{ exit !(length(a)==NR/2) }' set1 set2
# same as previous, requires >= gnu awk 3.1.5
```

**Set Cardinality**

```
$ wc -l set | cut -d' ' -f1    # outputs number of elements in set

$ wc -l < set

$ awk 'END { print NR }' set
```

**Subset Test**

```
$ comm -23 <(sort subset | uniq) <(sort set | uniq) | head -1
# outputs something if subset is not a subset of set
# does not putput anything if subset is a subset of set

$ awk 'NR==FNR { a[$0]; next } { if !($0 in a) exit 1 }' set subset
# returns 0 if subset is a subset of set
# returns 1 if subset is not a subset of set
```

**Set Union**

```
$ cat set1 set2     # outputs union of set1 and set2
                    # assumes they are disjoint

$ awk 1 set1 set2   # ditto

$ cat set1 set2 ... setn   # union over n sets

$ cat set1 set2 | sort -u  # same, but assumes they are not disjoint

$ sort set1 set2 | uniq

# sort -u set1 set2

$ awk '!a[$0]++'           # ditto
```

**Set Intersection**

```
$ comm -12 <(sort set1) <(sort set2)  # outputs insersect of set1 and set2

$ grep -xF -f set1 set2

$ sort set1 set2 | uniq -d

$ join <(sort -n A) <(sort -n B)

$ awk 'NR==FNR { a[$0]; next } $0 in a' set1 set2
```

**Set Complement**

```
$ comm -23 <(sort set1) <(sort set2)
# outputs elements in set1 that are not in set2

$ grep -vxF -f set2 set1           # ditto

$ sort set2 set2 set1 | uniq -u    # ditto

$ awk 'NR==FNR { a[$0]; next } !($0 in a)' set2 set1
```

**Set Symmetric Difference**

```
$ comm -3 <(sort set1) <(sort set2) | sed 's/\t//g'
# outputs elements that are in set1 or in set2 but not both

$ comm -3 <(sort set1) <(sort set2) | tr -d '\t'

$ sort set1 set2 | uniq -u

$ cat <(grep -vxF -f set1 set2) <(grep -vxF -f set2 set1)

$ grep -vxF -f set1 set2; grep -vxF -f set2 set1

$ awk 'NR==FNR { a[$0]; next } $0 in a { delete a[$0]; next } 1;
       END { for (b in a) print b }' set1 set2
```

**Power Set**

```
$ p() { [ $# -eq 0 ] && echo || (shift; p "$@") |
        while read r ; do echo -e "$1 $r\n$r"; done }
$ p `cat set`

# no nice awk solution, you are welcome to email me one:
# peter@catonmat.net
```

**Set Cartesian Product**

```
$ while read a; do while read b; do echo "$a, $b"; done < set1; done < set2

$ awk 'NR==FNR { a[$0]; next } { for (i in a) print i, $0 }' set1 set2
```

**Disjoint Set Test**

```
$ comm -12 <(sort set1) <(sort set2)  # does not output anything if disjoint

$ awk '++seen[$0] == 2 { exit 1 }' set1 set2 # returns 0 if disjoint
                                         # returns 1 if not
```

**Empty Set Test**

```
$ wc -l < set            # outputs 0  if the set is empty
                         # outputs >0 if the set is not empty

$ awk '{ exit 1 }' set   # returns 0 if set is empty, 1 otherwise
```

**Minimum**

```
$ head -1 <(sort set)    # outputs the minimum element in the set

$ awk 'NR == 1 { min = $0 } $0 < min { min = $0 } END { print min }'
```

**Maximum**

```
$ tail -1 <(sort set)    # outputs the maximum element in the set

$ awk '$0 > max { max = $0 } END { print max }'
```

Answer (score 2):

I like @fedorqui's use of *awk* for setups where one has enough memory to fit all the "remove these" lines: a concise expression of an in-memory approach.

But for a scenario where the size of the lines to remove is large relative to current memory, and reading that data into an in-memory data structure is an invitation to fail or thrash, consider an ancient approach: sort/join

```
sort main.txt > main_sorted.txt
sort removethese.txt > removethese_sorted.txt

join -t '' -v 1 main_sorted.txt removethese_sorted.txt > output.txt
```

Notes:

- this does not preserve the order from main.txt: lines in output.txt will be sorted
- it requires enough disk to be present to let sort do its thing (temp files), and store same-size sorted versions of the input files
- having join's -v option do just what we want here - print "unpairable" from file 1, drop matches - is a bit of serendipity
- it does not directly address locales, collating, keys, etc. - it relies on defaults of sort and join (-t with an empty argument) to match sort order, which happen to work on my current machine

Comment: Interesting answer! Note though that sorting a 100MB file can be also very time consuming.