# Match common IDs between two huge csv files

Tags: bash, csv, replace, awk

I need to compare two huge csv files with a thousand of entries like bellow:

```
id;val

1;a
2;b 
3;c
```

Ans second file has the following structure

```
id1;entry    
1;002
2;x90 
5;d07
```

The desired result is to match and combine the lines with the same value for id/id1 and create a third csv file with only matched entries showing bellow:

```
idR;valR;entryR
1;a;002
2;b;x90
```

To accomplish this I can load each file in a distinct database table and perform a select like this to retrieve all matched values:

```
select tb1.id, tb1.val tb2.entry 
  from tb1, tb2
 where tb1.id = tb2.1
```

At once I can retrieve all values desired with this approach.

But let's suppose these files could be sorted and in this way use it's possible to use awk to print the results for a entries with the same values for id and id1. The best that I can do is to create two associative arrays for each value and perform a binary search using awk and sed/cut?

It's possible to load these two files and combine them at once to produce a final csv file with the results?

Or I can to this with perl with standard lib?

Comment: theres actually a standard utility called [`join`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/join) which can do this

Comment: Are the files small enough to load into memory?

Comment: You say the files are CSV but the examples you show are space-separated. Edit your question to be clear, consistent, and precise - if your files are space-separated stop talking about CSV and if they're comma separated then show that as your sample input/output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can do this with standard [`join`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/join) utility

**file1.txt**

```
1 a
2 b
3 c
```

**file2.txt**

```
1 002
2 x90
5 d07
```

**join example**

```
join -1 1 -2 1 -o 1.1,1.2,2.2 file1.txt file2.txt
```

here join is joining from file1.field1 to file2.field2 and outputting the fields specified with the -o flag

**output**

```
1 a 002
2 b x90
```

Answer (score 5):

Load the information in memory with `awk` and then print the line if the `id` matches:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$2; next} ($1 in a) {print $1, $2, a[$1]}' f2 f1
1 a 002
2 b x90
```

#### Explanation

The basic idea is to do `things` when reading `file1` and `other_things` when reading `file2`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {things; next} {other_things}' file1 file2
```

In our case, `things` is to store the content of `file2` in memory, mapping every id to its value.

Then, it goes through `file1` and prints the content of the line, together with the mapped value, if there is a common id.

Comment: note I removed the headers on your file, since it doesn't seem to be important. If they are, let us know.

Comment: Note2: `awk` performs quite well in these kind of problems. See [Remove duplicates from text file based on second text file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30820894/1983854) and the time comparisons.

Comment: Note that this solution does not require the input files to be sorted while the `join` solution does. What the perl solution needs is a mystery :-).

Comment: Perl solution doesn't require much at all - but it does use more memory because it splices them whilst there.

Comment: @Sobrique wrt my comment about join and awk, the question is does the perl solution require the input files to be sorted or not.

Comment: Nope. It sorts 'em itself. (This might be an undesired side effect of course)

Comment: FYI for output - the `awk` solution will print the `f2` lines that exist in `f1` in input order first and then the `f1` lines that don't exist in `f2` will be printed afterwards in random order. The `join` solution will print the lines in merged input order but since they need to be sorted first for `join` to work, that's no better in terms of output order than just sorting the `awk` output.

Comment: Thanks guys so much for your help! The join solution works also in Solaris!

Comment: @Bera and `awk` also works in Solaris, only that you need to use `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk`.

Comment: yes, I verified this after search from distinct bash tools available on solaris. Thank you again so much!

Answer (score 2):

Size is the difficult part, as to merge files you may need to read in the whole lot.

However for a general solution the the problem in perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;

my %count_of;
my @field_order;

foreach my $file (@ARGV) {
    my $csv = Text::CSV->new( { binary => 1 } );
    open( my $input, "<", $file ) or die $!;
    my $header_row = $csv->getline($input);
    foreach my $header (@$header_row) {
        if ( not $count_of{$header} ) {
            push( @field_order, $header );
        }
        $count_of{$header}++;
    }
}

print "Common headers:\n";
my @common_headers = grep { $count_of{$_} >= @ARGV } keys %count_of;
print join( "\n", @common_headers );

my %lookup_row;
my $key_field;
if (@common_headers) { $key_field = shift @common_headers };

foreach my $file (@ARGV) {
    my $csv = Text::CSV->new( { binary => 1 } );
    open( my $input, "<", $file ) or die $!;
    my @headers = @{ $csv->getline($input) };
    $csv->column_names(@headers);
    while ( my $row_hr = $csv->getline_hr($input) ) {
        my $key = $.;
        if ($key_field) {
            $key = $row_hr->{$key_field};
        }
        $lookup_row{$key}{$file} = $row_hr;
    }
    close($input);
}

my $csv_out = Text::CSV->new( { binary => 1 } );
my $header_row = \@field_order;
$csv_out->print( \*STDOUT, $header_row );
print "\n";

foreach my $key ( sort keys %lookup_row ) {
    my %combined_row;
    foreach my $file ( sort keys %{ $lookup_row{$key} } ) {
        foreach my $header (@field_order) {
            if ( $lookup_row{$key}{$file}{$header} ) {
                if (   not defined $combined_row{$header}
                    or not $combined_row{$header} eq
                    $lookup_row{$key}{$file}{$header} )
                {
                    $combined_row{$header}
                        .= $lookup_row{$key}{$file}{$header};
                }
            }
        }
    }
    my @row = @combined_row{@field_order};
    $csv_out->print( \*STDOUT, \@row );
    print "\n";
}
```

Note that `Text::CSV` can be altered to redirect output to a file handle rather than `STDOUT` which is probably not what you want for large files (or y'know, just `> output.csv`. )

You can also configure the delimiter for `Text::CSV` via `sep_char`:

```
my $csv = Text::CSV -> new ( { binary => 1, sep_char => "\t" } );
```

I was unclear what your separator was, so have assumed comma (as you refer to `csv`).

Script above will pick out a common field and merge on that, or line number if none exists.

Note:

This script reads files into memory and merges them there, sorting and joining on a common key. It will sort based on this for output. It's therefore memory greedy, but should 'just work' in a lot of cases. Just specify the filenames `splice.pl file1.csv file2.csv file3.csv`

If there is a common field in these files, it'll join on those and output in order. If there isn't, it'll use line number.

Comment: Thank you for you nice code! Perl programmers are all gurus!