# BASH Grep for Specific Email Address in CSV

Tags: bash, email, csv, variables, grep

I'm trying to compare two CSV files by reading the first line-by-line and grepping the second file for a match. Using `Diff` is not a viable solution. I seem to be having a problem with having the email address stored as a variable when I grep the second file.

```
#!/bin/bash

LANG=C
head -2 $1 | tail -1 | while read -r line; do
  line=$( echo $line | sed 's/\n//g' )
  echo $line
  cat $2 | cut -d',' -f1 | grep -iF "$line"
done
```

Variable $line contains an email address that DOES exist in file $2, but I'm not getting any results.

What am I doing wrong?

File1

```
Email
email@verizon.net
email@gmail.com
email@yahoo.com
```

File2

```
email,,,,
email@verizon.net,,,,
email@gmail.com,,,,
email@yahoo.com,,,,
```

Comment: Can you post your entire implementation?

Comment: Ok. Updated the post. This version is reading just the second line of the first file, because I know that it is a match.

Comment: probably a simple `awk` would be best than piping some many things! See something similar: [Remove duplicates from text file based on second text file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30820894/1983854)

Comment: Well I could just do 

`grep -iF "$line" $2`

But that's not working either. So, the cut and cat statements are just for removing variable behavior.

Comment: maybe try this: #!/bin/bash

cmp -s filename_1 filename_2 > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
    echo is different
else
    echo is not different
fi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given:

```
# csv_0.csv
email
me@me.com
you@me.com
fee@me.com
```

and

```
# csv_1.csv
email,foo,bar,baz,bim
bee@me.com,3,2,3,4
me@me.com,4,1,1,32
you@me.com,7,4,6,6
gee@me.com,1,2,2,6
me@me.com,5,7,2,34
you@me.com,22,3,2,33
```

I ran

```
$ pattern=$(head -2 csv_0.csv | tail -1 | sed s/,.*//g)
$ grep $pattern csv_1.csv
me@me.com,4,1,1,32
me@me.com,5,7,2,34
```

To do this for *each* line in `csv_0.csv`

```
#!/bin/bash

LANG=C
filename="$1"
{
  read # don't read csv headers
  while read line
  do
      pattern=$(echo $line | sed s/,.*//g)
      grep $pattern $2
  done
} <"$filename"
```

Then

```
$ ./csv_read.sh csv_2.csv csv_3.csv
me@me.com,4,1,1,32
me@me.com,5,7,2,34
you@me.com,7,4,6,6
you@me.com,22,3,2,33
```

Comment: Hmm... It seems to keep spitting out the @yahoo.com email addys over and over, but does not spit out the exact email address matches...

Comment: I have no context for this error. The above works perfectly on my machine. I don't know what your specific error is.

Comment: Let me be more clear. I am perfectly willing to help, but you make reference to specifics about your issue I would have no way of knowing about (@yahoo.com addresses?). What I provided you is a general, go-right path demonstration of the underlying question you asked. I am of the opinion that it meets the criteria of an answer. If you need further assistance, please be detailed about what you are asking. If my answer meets the criteria of a response, please accept the answer.

Comment: Actually, I apologize. It is not printing just the yahoo.com emails; It is matching NO emails except for empty lines. When it encounters an empty line, it matches EVERY line of file 2. So basically its not printing any matches.

Comment: @user3204352 Sounds like this is better handled in chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94018/bash-grep-for-specific-email-address-in-csv

Comment: My rank is too weak for chat :(

Comment: Ok. Have you tried to run my script using the files I included on your system? Did it work?

Comment: Ok. So it did work on your samples. The question then would be, why would it not work on my files? The only thing I can think of is that File 1 is JUST email addresses. File 2 is in this format: Email,,,, (4 trailing commas). But grep should still be able to match it, correct? But it's not.  Hmm...

Comment: Hmmm. I edited the data above to match your format. The script works fine for me. Can you post actual (or slightly edited to remove sensitive information) lines from your files? Just a few should suffice. Add to your question.

Comment: So I tested my script against your data and it works with one exception. Per this thread: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916352/shell-script-read-missing-last-line) you need to have a new line at the end of your data file.

Comment: Not sure how else to help. You appreciate you accepting my answer.