# Removing ALL Duplicate Rows Notepad++

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

Is it possible to remove *ALL* duplicated rows in Notepad++, not leaving any occurrences of a duplicated line?

For example, I have a file:

```
jkekeuuuuuuuuuuuuuudlllemmmmmmmmeldjsllllllllllll.d,mmmm
lakjsd;lkuejjjjjjjjdmalejsssssssssssssssssssieeeeee
eyoiuddddddddkeousmsouyejjjjjjjjjjjjdnenooyyy
jkekeuuuuuuuuuuuuuudlllemmmmmmmmeldjsllllllllllll.d,mmmm
jkekeuuuuuuuuuuuuuudlllemmmmmmmmeldjsllllllllllll.d,mmmm
```

And I'd like to end up with:

```
lakjsd;lkuejjjjjjjjdmalejsssssssssssssssssssieeeeee
eyoiuddddddddkeousmsouyejjjjjjjjjjjjdnenooyyy
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing duplicate rows in Notepad++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958350/removing-duplicate-rows-in-notepad)

Comment: @P0W No, that question asks `how to remove all but one` duplicate; mine is `how to remove all`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Notepad++ cannot do it. Only can leave original lines.
In **SynWrite** editor you can write in Console panel some Python script to do it. Maybe even in Notepad++ you can use "Python Script" plugin.