# \u0119 to ę in notepad++

Tags: unicode, notepad++

I have searched all over the Internet for an answer.  I have achieved this once before, but I can't remember how I did this...

I have a long text file with alot of encoded characters, for example

```
\u0119,\u015b\\u0107
```

How do I change characters like `\u0119` to `ę`, etc?

Answer (score 3):

This question is not off-topic. In past I also use notepad++ for programing. Today i use Atom. You can find a lot questions about notepad++ in stack overflow - for instance: [Removing duplicate rows in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958350/removing-duplicate-rows-in-notepad?rq=1) or this [Convert tabs to spaces in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455037/convert-tabs-to-spaces-in-notepad?rq=1) (and many more). So please do not give minus points to this question.

---

Answer: I assume that when you go to menu>Encoding you will see 'Encde in UTF-8.'

I use this site to create part of my answer: https://superuser.com/questions/576431/notepad-inserting-special-unicode-characters-in-utf-8

If you see character codes like \u0119,\u015b\u0107 in your file this probably mean that they are just on encoded - and their codes are put expliicty as raw text.

So to change this codes into UTF-8 characters, go to

1. menu>run>run> type: charmap> click run
2. the windows charmap will show up, so check ''advanced view' an there put you character code (without \u prefix - so for instance only 0119) in filed 'go to Unicode'. Then click on 'select' and 'copy' and close window
3. Then go to menu>search>replace and in filed 'replece with' past you character, and inf filed 'find what' put its code (with prefix, for instance \u0119). And click 'Replace All'
4. Do steps 1-3 for each character code (you can check thad your done when you click menu>find> and type '\u' in "find what". If you not find any code then you job is end.

Comment: I added the character map program to my taskbar as I use it like this a lot.  Very handy.  Leave advanced mode on and it will remember that the next time you run it.  I really feel there is a need for a keyboard shortcut to enter unicode, much like the ALT+Keypad# feature which works well with everything else.  You can't use the ALT with the + feature in things like NotePad++, sadly.