# How can i remove duplicated lines (txt file)?

Tags: notepad++, lines

today I was trying to remove duplicate lines on a simple text file, something like:

```
input (list.txt):

hello
hello
try

output (list.txt):
try
```

i was trying with notepad++ to remove duplicate rows and remove the remaining one but nothing.
is there a software o some function for do this with notepad++?

thanks.

Comment: If you have the relative plugin available, [this might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958350/removing-duplicate-rows-in-notepad)

Comment: @PaulT. i tried with TextFX but remove and keep 1 row i need to remove all rows

Comment: Oh, I see. Are there only single words, or can there more than one word duplicated across lines? ... and is there only a few lines, or are we talking hundred of lines?

Answer (score 9):

Assuming the file is sorted, to have all duplicate lines together.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(.+(?:\R|$))\1+`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           : beginning of line
  (         : start group 1
    .+      : 1 or more any character but newline
    (?:     : start non capture group
      \R    : any kind of linebreak
     |      : OR
      $     : end of line
    )       : end group
  )         : end group 1
  \1+       : back-reference to group 1, may appear 1 or more times
```

**Result for given example:**

```
try
```

Comment: If you want to leave a single occurrence of the lines, put `\1` in 'Replace with'.

Comment: @GabrielLuci has an important point.  I copied the regex and used it and figured out I needed the \1 in the replacement field, then came back and saw his comment.  I think this is a common enough variation of the technique that including it in the solution makes it easier for future visitors.  But it is a terrific elegant solution. (I used to used TEXTFX's sort/unique option)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with php by exploding each line to an array then using the array_unique to get rid of duplicate values then implode the array using \n as a seperator. It can be done in php with 6 lines of code or less 
readfile
explode file
unique_array file
implode file
write file
close file
return file

Comment: It would be better (an improved answer) to show the actual PHP code that you describe as an example, as the OP might not know PHP.