# Notepad++: find all columns of a table

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am currently trying to figure out, how to find all columns of a table within an SQL statement using Regex in notepad++.

Lets take this query:

```
select
  a.id,
  a.id || a.name,
  a.age,
  b.id
From a,b
```

Now, I wat to retrieve all columns for a using regex - the problem the query itself is much larger and I do not want to have to go through the whole query.

The desired result is:

```
id
name
age
```

I already figured out that with

```
(?<=a\.)(\S+)
```

I match the desired strings, but Notepad++ still returns the whole lines and not only the words I need.

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Sorry, it is not that clear. Try `\ba\.(\S+)\b|(?s:.)` and replace with `(?1$1\n:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this 2 step approach to extract values after `a.`:

```
Find:         \ba\.(\w+)|(?s:.)
Replace With: (?1$1\n:)
```

Then, you need to [remove duplicate lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958350/removing-duplicate-rows-in-notepad) to get the expected results.

**Details**

- `\ba\.` - a `a.` substring as a whole word
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars (the group value will be kept + an LF will be appended in the replacement pattern)
- `|` - or
- `(?s:.)` - any char (it will be removed).

The `(?1$1\n:)` replacement means that the Group 1 value will be output and a line ending LF symbol will be appended to the result if Group 1 matches, else, empty string will be used as a replacement.

Comment: @ArunGowdru Sorry, SO  glitches here, I  re-posted the answer by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe "matching non greedy" using "?" and looking for word boundaries can help? The expression would look like this (add a ? in the last bracket):

```
(?<=a\.)(\S+?\b)
```

This just came into my mind as I read the question, didn't check it on functionality.

[More information on non-greedy modifier can be found here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898998/how-can-i-write-a-regex-which-matches-non-greedy)

Comment: Could you please explain why you think it may help? Do you know how lazy subpatterns at the end of patterns behave? They match the least amount of chars possible. `+?` matches 1, `*?` match 0.

Comment: As the TO wants to get "only the words" and not "the whole lines" this would be my approach - to just select as few characters as possible

Comment: You do not get as few as possible, with `\S+?` at the end of the pattern, you only get 1, even if there are more.