# How to delete duplicate numbers in notepad ++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I've been trying to do use the `^(.*?)$\s+?^(?=.*^\1$)` but it doesnt work.

I have this scenario:

```
9993990487 - 9993990487
9993990553 - 9993990553
9993990554 - 9993990559
9993990570 - 9993990570
9993990593 - 9993990596
9993990594 - 9993990594
```

And I would want to delete those that are "duplicate" and spect the following:

```
9993990487
9993990553
9993990554 - 9993990559
9993990570
9993990593 - 9993990596
9993990594
```

I would really appreciate some help since its 20k+ numbers I have to filter. Or maybe another program, but it's the only one I have available in this PC.

Thanks,

Josue

Comment: `^(\d+)\h+-\h+\1$` and replace with `$1`

Comment: take a look at this post, maybe it will help:<br/>
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958350/removing-duplicate-rows-in-notepad>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^(\d+)\h+-\h+\1$
```

Replace with `$1`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/u6jU8g/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `\h+-\h+` - a `-` char enclosed with 1+ horizontal whitespaces
- `\1` - an inline backreference to Group 1 value
- `$` - end of a line.

The replacement is a `$1` placeholder that replaces the match with the Group 1 value.

Demo and settings:

[image]

Comment: It worked fine in the regex demo, but when I tried in this PC it doesn't work. Thanks for the help Wiktor!

Comment: @Josue It works alright in Notepad++, too. I added a **proof**.