# Find duplicates in notepad++

Tags: duplicates, notepad++

I have a notepad++ file with duplicate words. I want to remove both of the duplicate words, here is an example of what I have. The accounts obviously don't work.

```
rajov517@omibrown.com:^tQ%De:ODk5NDc3MzgxNjU4NjAzNTIw.YWzVmw.RzXFWpm7IJJ8k7pHuxO7CTNK0
wogip240@omibrown.com:Vz18)E:ODk5NDc3MzgyNTc3MTQ3OTE1.YWzVmw.NO683x8kr-vtREzxNzswrvys0
nege5819@settags.com:0vgwJc:ODk5NDc3Mzg0NzY2NTYyMzE1.YWzVnA.YWR9PQH4bVNAbV6J8Qg1-Nrn4
gete7799@otozuz.com:yo(6Kl:ODk5NDc3MzkwNTU4OTA4NDI2.YWzVnQ.QA2_z11bePt5IPNazm97rahJQ
kigopeh2@wii999.com:x*g^Nt:ODk5NDc3MzkxMDkxNTY4NjQw.YWzVnQ.NUA1xfPHoYQrb2Jvpg8LxA__o
seb53316@smuvaj.com:$PFC&H:ODk5NDc3Mzk0NjIzMTgwODIx.YWzVng.l8PJnzsRKII0ax7Q4FroanGQs

ODk5NDc3MzgxNjU4NjAzNTIw.YWzVmw.RzXFWpm7IJJ8k7pHuxO7CTNK0
ODk5NDc3Mzk0NjIzMTgwODIx.YWzVng.l8PJnzsRKII0ax7Q4FroanGQs
```

So I want to remove both the line from above and below that are duplicates.

Comment: this question has been answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958350/removing-duplicate-rows-in-notepad#:~:text=As%20of%20Notepad%2B%2B%20version,Line%20Operations%20%3E%20Remove%20Duplicate%20Lines%20.

Comment: I tried to use the TextFX plugin but I can't figure out how to solve the problem that I have.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find a certain duplicate use the ctrl+f for searching matches and then just delete manually the duplicated text.
Edit: You have another option, and it's to install a plug-in called text++ that has been shown above my answer.
Take care,
Ori

Comment: I tried to use the TextFX plugin but I can't figure out how to solve the problem that I have.

Comment: Goto textFX Tools, ctal + a everything and then sort line case sensitive.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't get rid of the duplicates