# In Notepad++, how do I select all partially duplicate lines and keep only the first instance?

Tags: regex, duplicates, notepad++

The lines in question are the ones that have a name, and then a time references at the end. I need to find all the lines with duplicate names. Keeping only the first instance with the earliest timestamp, and deleting all the rest. I do not want to delete the duplicate text from the offending lines. I need the whole line gone. So when I am done, there will only be one entry of each remaining. I cannot sort and delete duplicate lines because their positions must stay in tact and underneath their corresponding track numbers (unless there's a way to handle that issue afterwards).

So far this task is being done quite easily using the "Remove Duplicates" function in Microsoft Excel. But it is a hassle leaving the Notepad++ environment, copying out, doing edits in Excel, and then copying back over to Notepad++. It gets in the way of me creating internal macros and automating tasks across all open files. There are thousands of files that need this task done, along with many other edits. I have figured out how to get everything else done from within Notepad++, except this one *feat*. I have tried an infinite number of regex commands, bookmark tricks, etc. No go. I have been trying to leave Excel behind and figure out a way to do this in Notepad++ for weeks. I could do this fine if the duplicates were all in sequential order, line for line. But they are not.

**Here is an example:**

### **Before**

```
Track 1    Retakes
        E07-P09 - Retake    00:00:12:370
        E07-P09 - Retake    00:00:14:572
        E07-P09 - Retake    00:00:17:711
        E07-P09 - Retake    00:00:22:388
        E07-P09 - Retake    00:00:23:939
        E07-P09 - Retake    00:00:30:218
        E07-P09 - Retake    00:00:32:177
Track 2    Med Signals
        TV Effect    00:03:35:983
        TV Effect    00:03:37:743
        TV Effect    00:04:18:848
        Dio Effect   00:04:17:607
        TV Effect    00:08:07:754
        TV Effect    00:08:37:808
        Dio Effect   00:08:37:567
Track 3    Rad Tuning
        Tuning NF HQ    00:10:46:358
Track 4    Super Clips
        Colde Square - Mentality    00:03:37:935
        Colde Square - Mentality    00:08:08:465
Track 5    Audi Bed
        Royal Fade into Grey    00:00:00:000
        The Sidas    00:04:19:535
        Royal Fade into Grey    00:08:39:400
```

### **After**

```
Track 1    Retakes
        E07-P09 - Retake    00:00:12:370
Track 2    Med Signals
        TV Effect    00:03:35:983
        Dio Effect    00:04:17:607
Track 3    Rad Tuning
        Tuning NF HQ    00:10:46:358
Track 4    Super Clips
        Colde Square - Mentality    00:03:37:935
Track 5    Audi Bed
        Royal Fade into Grey    00:00:00:000
        The Sidas    00:04:19:535
```

There are tabs separating every section and double tabs at the beginning of the lines with timestamps.

Comment: Regex+notepad is not well suited to this task. Consider writing some code in say python.

Comment: If you do not mind to click multiple times 'replace all' button try to search for the following pattern: `^(( ++.+ ).*+)((?>\R(?!\2) .+)*)(?:\n\2.*)+` and replace with `$1$3` (see regex101 demo [step1](https://regex101.com/r/5ahiY7/1), [step2](https://regex101.com/r/5ahiY7/2)). You need to repeat this as often as it matches (until no more replacements are done). Not sure, if this works with all your input though, was just a quick try.

Comment: @Bohemian

I looked into using python vaguely, being that it has come up a few times. Haven't tried it, but if all else fails I may have to go that route. Don't really have time to dive into an unfamiliar language but if I can spend a little time to learn enough to achieve this task, I will go for it as an extra option. Can you share some links or info to expedite this process? Either way. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @bobble bubble

Thanks for the attempt. It didn't work at all though. Using regular expression with match newline checked or unchecked. Returns with "no occurrences found" or "Can't find text" error.

As I mentioned to [@]InSync as well, it seems regex101 is giving good results, in both of your cases, the regex given seemed to have produced the exact results I am looking for when applying the codes and my text there. So why is Notepad++ throwing back errors? I have tested this discrepancy with different code variations and the results are processed differently when applied in NPPP. Why?

Comment: @hummieru I read all your comments and @InSync's reply. Same for my pattern, if you use tabs, change to: [`^((\h++.+\h).*+)((?>\R(?!\2)\h.+)*)(?:\R\2.*)+`](https://regex101.com/r/5ahiY7/3) (same replacement `$1$3`). It's *not* a compatibility issue wihch InSync alreayd mentioned, also I have of course tested my pattern in NP++ before I wrote the comment. :) Hope one of our ideas work for you! Don't forget in my pattern you will need to click 'replaceAll' multiple times until no more matches are found (*without* dot match newline).

Comment: Nope. Same results. I copied your exact code into NP++ with regex and it comes back the same. "No text found" error. And "0 occurences". It seems that Stack did some formatting to my examples. I don't know if that's standard procedure, but I pasted my examples with the tabs, each tab was turned into 2 spaces. Either way It still is not working. I am doing everything else well. for some reason this one will not work for me.

Comment: Was just looking at the notes that shows how my post was edited. I see the what and most of the why the edits are made. Understood.

Comment: @hummieru Weird, [here is an img](https://gcdnb.pbrd.co/images/KDpxybCCobaz.png) how it worked for me [with this regex](https://regex101.com/r/5ahiY7/3) (using Notepad++ v8.5.7).

Answer (score 2):

There is already [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16293580) which explains how to remove all duplicate lines but the last. We can modify it a bit and apply a small trick so that it works for your use case, which is to keep the first.

First, let's make that regex a bit more specific:

```
^\h+                   # Match a line that starts with some horizontal whitespaces
(.+?)                  # then a name, which we capture,
\h{2,}                 # then at least two more whitespaces
(?:\d\d:){3}\d{3}\R    # before a timestamp at the end of that line.
(?=                    # This line must be followed by
  (?:\h++.+\R)*?       # any number of lines, but only in the same section,
  \h+\1\h{2,}          # then a line which has the same name as what we captured.
)                      #
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/RNLPd9/3).

However, that still only keep the last line. The way to make it works backwards is to, obviously, reverse the lines' order! Notepad++ has built-in support for this (more information can be found at [this *Super User* question](https://superuser.com/q/331098)): At the top menu, find *Edit*, then *Line Operations* and finally *Reverse Line Order*.

In conclusion: Reverse line order, replace the regex above with nothing, then reverse it back.

It should be noted that a small script in the language of your choice is probably a better solution, since a script is automated, allows code reusing and is much more flexible than regexes alone.

The settings should look something like this (*Replace with* is empty):

[image: Regular expression: Checked; Dot matches new line: Unchecked]

Comment: Ahh. Regex101.com Great site to learn, practice, test, experiment with regex in real time nice. Thank you for that link!

Comment: Thank you for that link, and the explanation of the commands!

Although the regex works fine on-site. When trying to apply it in NPPP, no go. Am I missing something? I reversed the order of the lines.

Edit>Line Operations>Reverse Line Order.

Added the regex to the Find what field with with regular expression selected

^\h+(.+?)\h{2,}(?:\d\d:){3}\d{3}\R(?=(?:\h++.+\R)*?\h+\1\h{2,})

As a result, I get the "Can't find the text" error.

Comment: Wasn't sure if "match newline" should be selected or not. Tried both ways, along with a couple of variations in the regex that I am familiar with. Same results every time. Wish I could add a picture to confirm. Doesn't seem to be an option in the comments though. Could share image link perhaps. From the regex.com results, this produces EXACTLY what I am trying to accomplish. Why doesn't it work in NPPP?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, aren't there different versions/engines/libraries of regex that may be implemented and/or utilitized differently by app devs and there software? Could it be that what regex101.com is using is not completely compatible with Notepad++?

Comment: @hummieru While it is true that Boost, the engine Notepad++ uses, is a bit different from PCRE2, I have verified that the regex is compatible with both. The settings should look something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3Xty.png).

Comment: So far I have found that Notepad++ find and replace functions use some type of Boost implementation, but the default on regex101 is using PCRE2. Boost is apparently not fully compatible with PCRE patterns. Its crazy. I was bugging out through this whole ordeal, thinking why something that seems so simple and standard would be this tough to get done. Learning the aforementioned and seeing advanced regex implementations in action using PCRE2 on regex101 shows me that this is very possible. As @bobble bubble said, his attempt was a "quick try", and it works fine using PCRE2.

Comment: @hummieru ..."*[i]f you do not mind to click multiple times 'replace all' button*", that is. Does my answer work for you, or should I delete it?

Comment: Sorry. I didn't see your reply until after that last comment. Been looking into this. Saw your image of the replace window in NPPP as well. You said you have confirmed this procedure in Notepad++ to be working? I am trying it myself with no results. I did test clicking multiple times but it does not recognize anything at all. 

Here is the code and screenshots link.

^\h+(.+?)\h{2,}(?:\d\d:){3}\d{3}\R(?=(?:\h++.+\R)*?\h+\1\h{2,})

Link To Screenshots:
https://mega.nz/folder/pjgWGaLK#PFUzAlV1jjHkqI8JM7i3FA

Thanks and appreciation for taking the time to help!

Comment: @hummieru It seems that you are using tabs as separators for the names and the timestamps; this is not the case with your question, since it uses 4 spaces in the example... Change `\h{2,}` to `\h+` then.